# Call an IDL routine from command line in Windows and prevent (or ignore) popup dialog boxes

Tags: idl-programming-language

I've written a short script (in another language, happens to be Python) which passes arguments to the command line as follows -

```
ildrt <path/filename.sav> -args p1 p2 --o1 --o2
```

where p, o are positional and optional arguments respectively (obvious). To get to the point, this script calls an IDL routine any number of times. Each time, the IDL virtual machine is loaded, the IDL routine runs until completion, rinse and repeat.

Unfortunately if an error occurs in the IDL routine execution a dialog box will popup and halt program execution until manually clicked. Since the idea is to run this as a batch process I want to ignore the dialog boxes, (accepting the error), and continue to the next run. Any thoughts on preferences or optional commands I can run IDL with to prevent the popups? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'm not following. Can't you just pass a flag to your program and then check that flag before popping up a dialog in your code? If you don't have access to the `.pro` code, then I don't think you can prevent the popups.

Comment: The popups were due to exceptions that came from the .pro file after it was called. I ended up just adding exception handling code in the .pro file. This, as you said, required access to that file, but the only way to prevent the popups seemed to be to catch the error. I still haven't found a way to just let the .pro file exit without confirmation on the error. Let me know if what I am asking makes sense and if you have any thoughts.